# How to get rid of a song stuck in my head?

Tags: music

Sometimes when I hear a song, I cannot stop singing it in my head for the rest of the day, and maybe even for a few days. This is annoying, because it usually happens with silly songs.

How can I get rid of the annoying silly song in my head?

Comment: Try eating a fresh apple. The chewing will dissipate an "earworm" according to some sources.

Answer (score 3):

The only proven method I know of to get rid of an "earworm" of that sort is to hear (or sing, hum, etc.) the song all the way to the end.  Once that's done, your mind will be able to let go of it and quit replaying a fragment over and over.

Replacing it with another song usually doesn't work, as you'll just have a fragment of that other song stuck instead...